# Is Azure Compute Emulator deprecated or by third party only now?

Tags: azure

I'm planning to write my own .NET app on my personal time so will take months. I google and found there are two Azure Emulator:

- Compute.
- Storage.

While Storage is not needed right now as I don't need blob, messaging and file services, **Compute** is what I need, so I can develop and debug app w/o connecting to Azure all the time, plus saving $$$.
However, MS site only has Storage for download at Azure SDK. Links for Compute are all not-found.

Is Compute Emulator dropped by MS? Or, it's now developed and supported by third party like this now? http://windows-azure-emulator.software.informer.com/
BTW, is it safe to download this one?

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to build?

Comment: BTW, plan to use it in conjunction w/ VS 2015 Community, hope it will work w/ Community. Appreciate any input.

Comment: @GauravMantri, web SPA app collect some form data from user, will utilize SQL Server.

Comment: Which Azure SDK version are you targeting?

Comment: And whether you're planning to deploy as Azure Web App or as Cloud Service? If it is Web App, then you can just deploy to local IIS or IIS Express

Comment: @OscarSiauw The latest. Only used Azure for Hello World when signing up w/ that free $200 credit a year ago.

Comment: @OscarSiauw You meant build now, deployment is a breeze and easy thing?

Comment: If you're building an Azure Web App, you don't need Compute Emulator. Just deploy to local IIS or IIS Express. For deployment to Azure, you have a number of options, but the easiest is through Web Deploy for "breeze and easy" deployment

Comment: @OscarSiauw Same if Web API is included?

Comment: @Jeb50 yes. You're still deploying the Web API as Azure Web App

Comment: @Jeb50 You need Compute Emulator if you're building Cloud Service (Web Role or Worker Role). But building and deploying a Web App is so much easier than building Cloud Service

Comment: @OscarSiauw The whole thing changes rapidly, is this answer still good? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017451/differences-between-azure-app-services-and-cloud-services

Comment: @Jeb50 That is still good as of today. Web App should be your first choice if you're building a simple / straight-forward web app

Comment: @OscarSiauw One off-topic question. Can I have my own domain say www.XYZ.net to be hosted in Azure?

Comment: You cannot host your domain in Azure. You have to host it somewhere else (GoDaddy or somewhere). However you can map your domain to your Azure website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those provided all input. 
Answer is: No need for any Emulator if building a Web App (or called site). Simply develop as you would using local IIS or IIS Express, of course Community is ok. Then when it's time to move to Azure, use "Web Deploy".
Details of What type of app/services you'd choose for Azure, refer to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm