# How to build a Rest API on Azure for a Documentdb database with Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have already created a Documentdb database and now i should build a REST API on Azure with Node.js. I have read the documentation, but i did't understand it good enough.

Cloud services could be a good solution, but if i didn't misunderstand, it is Python and .NET based.

If i want to build a REST API and an user interface voor the REST API, which services should i better use? Web apps? API apps? Or any another product?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform#why-use-api-apps),

> An API app can take advantage of features offered by [Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-overview) and [Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop). The reverse is also true: if you use a web app or mobile app to host an API, it can take advantage of API Apps features such as Swagger metadata for client code generation and CORS for cross-domain browser access. The only difference between the three app types (API, web, mobile) is the name and icon used for them in the Azure portal.

An API app and a Web app will equally work for you. Currently, all of Web, Mobile and API Apps are collectively called App Services. For most scenarios, Web Apps is the best choice.

**More on this:**

[Azure Web API vs Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387073/azure-web-api-vs-web-app)

[Differences between Azure App Services and Cloud Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017451/differences-between-azure-app-services-and-cloud-services)